# Placement of "with" before an absolute clause

Tags: prepositional-phrases, ellipsis, adjuncts

> Normally, there is a selection in advance of a raising cam, with each feeder course being associated with a particular selection device.

This sentence has been chosen from "Knitting Technology" by David J Spencer.
If I write the above sentence in the following way, i.e if I omit ***with*** before the absolute clause, what differences will be appeared?

> Normally, there is a selection in advance of a raising cam, each feeder course being associated with a particular selection device.

I would appreciate it if anybody helped me to get rid from this awkward situation.

Answer (score 4):

With-construction: I can't work with all the children crying. 
"with + a participle construction" expresses a special circumstance of the main clause.
Sometimes "with" can be dropped. But sometimes the connection between main clause and participle construction can become unclear as in this case:

I can't work, all the children crying.

Added: An old post of mine on another forum:
with-construction (with + noun + participle)

If you don't know this special construction, you have difficulty to understand it.

A typical example: I can't work | with all the children crying.
The sense of it is: I can't work when all the children are crying.
This construction is very old and was already in use in Latin (ablativus absolutus).

You can choose whether you consider "crying" as a participle or gerund. Grammars treat it as participle.
I tend to see it as gerund and explain the sentence as
- I can't work with all the children (in the act of) crying.

Of course, it will take you quite a time till you can think in such constructions. The advantage of the 
with-construction is you can add in a shortened and elegant way circumstantial facts for which
you normally need a subclause with a conjunction.

This is a whole chapter in grammars and you should have a lot of examples as there are some variants of this with-construction (My name as there is no standard term for this construction).

Comment: Would you like to give the link of post where you have described about with-construction (with + noun + participle)? Please, if it is possible, mention the link. It would be of great help for me.

Comment: @AzaharAli http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst54877_with---because-of.aspx - My post is far down, post no. 8